# Creating form and form doesn´t show

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 plugins, I create form and then save the generated code in the contact page. But, in the preview page didn't show any form.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share code of your contact us template .

Comment: hello prakash, i edit the my question. u can see the code in 2nd image i attached in quesstion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed out the **the_content** function to call. Please add this code in your template file from container start to container end. Please check the HTML as per your design .

```
<div class="contianer"><!--container start here -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- map column -->
        <div class="col-lg-8 mb-4">
            <!-- google map iframe goes here -->
        </div>
        <!-- contact details here  -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
            <?php the_content(); ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!--container end here -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Wordpress loop somewhere in that `contact-us.php` template, otherwise WP won't load what you define as content in the WP editor (which in your case is the content form)